# Network Redirect off subnet for Synergy in hosts file

Tags: routing, router, ipv4

Perhaps I'm off the right track here, but I'll describe what I'm trying to do first generalized and then why I want to do it.

**General Case**

I'm looking to redirect a specific IP address on a single computer, either through the hosts file or through my home router such that requests for the IP address of my work desktop, 10.14.0.29 will go to my home desktop, 192.168.1.12, when I am off my work network.

**Specifically**

I'm running Synergy on my laptop, and the synergy client will not allow the entry of multiple IP addresses to look for servers on. Currently, I take my laptop to work and have to enter '10.14.0.29' in the client, then take it home and change it to '192.168.1.12', thus changing it twice a day. I have entered a support ticket to the Synergy devs to add this feature ([view it here](http://synergy-foss.org/spit/issues/details/3735/) and vote it up if you want). This is annoying to say the least.

I cannot change the IP address scheme of my entire office, nor do I want to make my home network operate on 10.14.0.XXX. I want 10.14.0.29 to 'bounce to' 192.168.1.12 when I'm at home (either 10.14.0.29 is unavailable or doesn't have a synergy server running on it).

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit of a kludge, but I guess you could keep two synergy.conf files and use a script to update them. Potentially the script could be configured to detect which network you were attached to. Obviously the way you would approach that would depend on your OS.

Synergy can use hostnames rather than IP addresses, so while adjusting your IP range at home/work might be a harrowing prospect, it may be less painful to rename your home desktop to have the same name as your work PC. It's not something I'd do, but you might find it tolerable. Again, depending very much on your infrastructure at home there may be a way to make WORKPCNAME resolve to home.pc.ip.address in DNS.

Comment: I have an ASUS RT-N56U router, but I'm using Google's DNS on Windows 8 computers. If I have two entries in my hosts file, could I have EXAMPLE resolve to the two different IP addresses?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your home network router that you have, it might be possible to define a NAT rule as the following:

- You define a rule in your home network that any traffic towards your office server IP will be directed towards your home network Machine to which Synergy communicates.

I dont know what type of home router do you have, but you will have to do some testing with NAT configuration.

Comment: I have an ASUS RT-N56U http://www.asus.com/Networking/RTN56U/

Comment: Can I use NAT rules for IP addresses off the home subnet? I.E. define 10.14.0.29 -> 192.168.1.12 when my home subnet mask is 255.255.255.0?